# No API (Private or Public) accessible in external Tomcat server

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I am new to Spring Boot and have deployed my application on an external Tomcat server. But I am unable to access resource on external Tomcat.

http://127.0.0.1:8282/apk/getpublicresource

[image]

However if I run the same API on embedded Tomcat it will work fine.

[image]

This is my application.properties

```
server..port=9998
```

This is `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>wardemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>wardemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!--tomcat dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--tomcat dependency-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>wardemo</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is controller

```
package com.example.wardemo.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class BasicController {

 @RequestMapping("/getpublicresource")
    public String getPublicResource(){
     return "This is successful string";
 }



}
```

and this is application file

```
package com.example.wardemo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class WardemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WardemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(WardemoApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Note that I have done `maven clean` and then `maven package` to generate war file which I later renamed as `apk.war` and deployed it on the Tomcat server.

localhost access log

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [13/Apr/2023:11:39:47 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 7025
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [13/Apr/2023:11:39:48 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 3389
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [13/Apr/2023:11:39:57 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 3389
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [13/Apr/2023:11:39:57 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 3389
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2023:11:40:21 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11428
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2023:11:40:24 +0530] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 401 2562
127.0.0.1 - admin [13/Apr/2023:11:40:30 +0530] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 200 21909
127.0.0.1 - admin [13/Apr/2023:11:41:11 +0530] "POST /manager/html/upload;jsessionid=04128590F1A0A51F5D264F6A0B4B59B6?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=035B8D1C50DC73D8D40BED7FDFA15C11 HTTP/1.1" 200 21317
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2023:11:41:40 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11428
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2023:11:42:25 +0530] "GET /getpublicresource HTTP/1.1" 404 768
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2023:11:59:49 +0530] "GET /apk/getpublicresource HTTP/1.1" 404 776
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2023:12:00:02 +0530] "GET /apk/ HTTP/1.1" 404 759
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2023:12:00:17 +0530] "GET /apk/getpublicresource HTTP/1.1" 404 776
127.0.0.1 - admin [13/Apr/2023:12:26:49 +0530] "POST /manager/html/undeploy?path=/apk&org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=98498E114DA95D114733AF99428D5916 HTTP/1.1" 403 3529
127.0.0.1 - admin [13/Apr/2023:12:27:00 +0530] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 200 21317
127.0.0.1 - admin [13/Apr/2023:12:27:04 +0530] "POST /manager/html/undeploy?path=/apk&org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=7FA9400C55D50F50AAE4871469D79BA8 HTTP/1.1" 200 20158
127.0.0.1 - admin [13/Apr/2023:12:27:16 +0530] "POST /manager/html/upload?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=09BADD222A428BE969B677CB51BD0EC6 HTTP/1.1" 200 21317
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2023:12:27:21 +0530] "GET /apk/getpublicresource HTTP/1.1" 404 776
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2023:12:35:20 +0530] "GET /apk/getpublicresource HTTP/1.1" 404 776
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Apr/2023:13:11:07 +0530] "GET /apk/getpublicresource HTTP/1.1" 404 776
```

This is catalina log

```
13-Apr-2023 12:27:04.626 INFO [http-nio-8282-exec-34] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/apk]
13-Apr-2023 12:27:15.432 INFO [http-nio-8282-exec-33] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [D:\server\webapps\apk.war]
13-Apr-2023 12:27:16.100 SEVERE [http-nio-8282-exec-33] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [D:\server\webapps\apk.war]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:662)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:543)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1689)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:803)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1615)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:209)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:528)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:596)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:190)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:355)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:54)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/apk]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        ... 45 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: The device is not ready
        at org.apache.catalina.util.CharsetMapper.<init>(CharsetMapper.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.CharsetMapper.<init>(CharsetMapper.java:59)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getCharsetMapper(StandardContext.java:1397)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4754)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 46 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: The device is not ready
        at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.readBytes0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.readBytes(RandomAccessFile.java:390)
        at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:424)
        at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(RandomAccessFile.java:488)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.readFullyAt(ZipFile.java:1368)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.initDataOffset(ZipFile.java:922)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:938)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:455)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:175)
        at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:119)
        at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:504)
        at java.base/java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:420)
        at java.base/java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:409)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.CharsetMapper.<init>(CharsetMapper.java:76)
        ... 50 more
13-Apr-2023 12:27:16.105 INFO [http-nio-8282-exec-33] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [D:\server\webapps\apk.war] has finished in [673] ms
13-Apr-2023 12:34:54.313 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await Invalid shutdown command [GET /apk/getpublicresource HTTP/1.1] received
13-Apr-2023 12:34:54.313 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await Invalid shutdown command [GET /apk/getpublicresource HTTP/1.1] received
13-Apr-2023 12:34:54.320 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await Invalid shutdown command [GET /apk/getpublicresource HTTP/1.1] received
13-Apr-2023 12:34:55.360 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await Invalid shutdown command [GET /apk/getpublicresource HTTP/1.1] received
13-Apr-2023 12:34:55.360 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await Invalid shutdown command [GET /apk/getpublicresource HTTP/1.1] received
13-Apr-2023 12:34:55.367 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await Invalid shutdown command [GET /apk/getpublicresource HTTP/1.1] received
13-Apr-2023 12:35:00.389 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await Invalid shutdown command [GET /apk/getpublicresource HTTP/1.1] received
13-Apr-2023 12:35:00.392 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await Invalid shutdown command [GET /apk/getpublicresource HTTP/1.1] received
13-Apr-2023 12:35:00.394 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await Invalid shutdown command [GET /apk/getpublicresource HTTP/1.1] received
```

Comment: Did you try with http://127.0.0.1:9998/apk/getpublicresource URL ?

Comment: Also to defined port in application .properties you need to correct key like 
 'server.port=9998'

Comment: server.port=9998 will not work because he has deploy the war file in tomcat server. The server port will be specified by server.xml of that tomcat.

Comment: @VinhNT i do agree but his key got wrongly updated also yes he may need to look bin/server.xml to verify port .

Comment: His tomcat is working at 8282, and it is working well, otherwise, the first request will got other error: connection refuse. This case, I think he got some error while deploying apk.war to that tomcat server, he need to look for the tomcat deployment log to see what happened.

Comment: @AnandDwivedi Tomcat is running on 8282 port

Comment: Tried this url also 
http://127.0.0.1:9998/apk/getpublicresource

after modifying application.properties

Comment: @VinhNT which port do i have to look exactly in server.xml,there are many ports defined in this file,can you please specify

Comment: @VinhNT can you specify where to look exactly for tomcat deployment log

Comment: have you checked that the folder `apk` is succesfully credted under `<tomcat>/webapps` ?

Comment: The tomcat log is called catalina.out and is in `<tomcat>/logs`

Comment: I agree that your Tomcat is running correctly on :8282, but is the apk web app? Check the console or tomcat logs for evidence that app started. Check in webapps for a folder called apk. Try http://127.0.0.1:8282/manager - it will respond with 401 and setup instructions for user. Look for the apk in the list of webapps.

Comment: @AnandDwivedi i have added log detail into the question description. can you please look into it once

Comment: @VinhNT i have added log detail into the question description. can you please look into it once

Comment: @JohnWilliams i have added log detail into the question description. can you please look into it once

Comment: @ScaryWombat i have added log detail into the question description. can you please look into it once

Comment: The problem seems to be with `java.io.IOException: The device is not ready` - maybe in your properties file you are trying to reference some file with the wrong path?

Comment: It is having trouble expanding the apk.war file. I suspect the tomcat process lacks some rights in the filesystem. Try renaming apk.war to apk.zip and unzipping it in the webapps folder while tomcat is not running. It should create a folder apk inside webapps. Start tomcat and check logs and responses. If this works you need to investigate the tomcat process user, eg is it running as service.

Comment: @ScaryWombat told the right thing, when tomcat deploy your war file, it also attempted to initialize your app, and your app was failed to start because of IOException.